# Cent OS - MySQL Daemon failed to start

Tags: centos, mysql, cache, alternative-php-cache

I'm running AWS micro instance with 0.615 GB Memory.

I have APC running on it with 35 MB size max as default.

Now I have restarted mysqld and it wont start. It has just stopped. I really need to get this up and running now. Its highly urgent for me.

Below is the log, please share your experiences as to what would be the quickest fix to this.

Thanks in advance,

```
140111 14:49:32 [Warning] IP address '113.10.247.183' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140111 14:59:42 [Warning] IP address '59.53.68.15' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140111 21:01:00 [Warning] IP address '216.99.158.94' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140112  1:05:51 [Warning] IP address '117.41.249.134' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140112  2:06:52 [Warning] IP address '218.205.137.122' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140113  1:29:44 [Warning] IP address '50.23.54.2' has been resolved to the host name '50.23.54.2-static.reverse.softlayer.com', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
140113 12:49:09 [Warning] IP address '113.10.137.11' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140114  0:36:22 [Warning] IP address '198.13.101.242' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
140114  1:03:19 [Warning] IP address '182.18.30.92' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
140114 18:42:41 [Warning] IP address '183.136.213.198' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140114 23:22:28 [Warning] IP address '118.192.7.10' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140115  7:44:59 [Warning] IP address '198.13.101.242' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
140115 22:40:14 [Warning] IP address '111.68.3.106' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
140116  3:15:56 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

140116  3:15:56 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
140116  3:15:56  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140116  3:15:58  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 7223004
140116  3:15:58 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:15:58 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:15:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:15:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:15:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:15:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:15:59 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:15:59 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:15:59 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:15:59 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:16:30 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:16:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:16:30 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:16:30 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:16:30 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:16:30 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:16:30 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:16:30 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:16:30 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:16:30 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:16:30 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:16:30 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:16:30 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:16:30 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:16:30 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:22:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:22:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:22:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:22:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:22:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:22:54 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:22:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:22:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:22:54 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:22:54 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:22:54 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:22:54 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:22:54 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:22:54 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:22:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:25:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:25:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:25:03 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:25:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:25:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:25:03 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:25:03 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:25:03 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:25:03 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:25:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:25:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:25:03 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:25:03 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:25:03 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:25:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:27:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:27:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:27:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:27:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:27:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:27:36 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:27:36 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:27:36 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:27:36 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:27:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:27:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:27:36 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:27:36 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:27:36 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:27:36 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:37:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:37:37 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:37:37 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:37:37 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:37:37 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:37:37 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:37:37 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:37:37 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:37:37 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:37:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:37:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:37:37 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:37:37 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:37:37 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:37:37 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:39:10 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:39:10 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:39:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:39:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:39:10 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:39:10 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:39:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:39:10 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:39:10 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:39:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:39:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:39:10 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:39:10 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:39:10 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:39:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:40:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:40:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:40:03 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:40:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:40:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:40:03 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:40:03 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:40:03 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:40:03 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:40:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:40:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:40:03 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:40:03 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:40:03 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:40:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:41:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:41:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:41:28 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:41:28 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:41:28 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:41:28 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:41:28 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:41:28 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:41:28 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:41:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:41:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:41:28 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:41:28 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:41:28 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:41:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:43:21 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:43:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:43:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:43:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:43:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:43:21 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:43:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:43:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:43:21 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:43:21 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:43:21 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:43:21 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:43:21 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:43:21 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:43:21 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140116 03:44:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140116  3:44:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140116  3:44:43 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140116  3:44:43 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140116  3:44:43 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
140116  3:44:43 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140116  3:44:43 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:44:43 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:44:43 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140116  3:44:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140116  3:44:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140116  3:44:43 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140116  3:44:43 [ERROR] Aborting

140116  3:44:43 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140116 03:44:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I have also tried upgrading mysql.

```
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the *important* part of your log:

```
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140116  3:15:59 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

(Errno 12 is "Cannot allocate memory")

So we see that MySQL tried to allocate 128 MB and failed to do so. That means your instance doesn't have enough memory left.

It could be you just have something running that's leaking memory, and rebooting the instance will get you up and running.

But it's more likely that you need to go through all your processes and see what is using up memory, and tune them appropriately to run in a micro instance, or upgrade the instance size.